# Eliminate a single row of a dataframe in R did not work

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

everyone!

I have  dataframe like the next one, lets call it DF

```
|Symbol |   Date    | volume |price |
|------------------------------------
|A      |2014-09-01 | 1      |   5  |
|A      |2014-09-02 | 3      |   8  |
|A      |2014-09-03 | 7      |   4  |
|A      |2014-09-06 |3       |   6  |
|A      |2014-09-08 |34      |   7  |
|A      |2014-09-09 |45      |  34  |
|A      |2014-09-10 |4       |   5  | 
|A      |2014-09-11 |9       |   7  |
|A      |2014-09-14 |8       |   6  |
|A      |2014-09-15 |4       |   4  |
|A      |2014-09-16 |0       |   7  |
|A      |2014-09-17 |4       |   7  |
```

And I have to eliminate only the row where the date is "2014-09-06" and the Symbol is "A"

I tried the next codes and did not work:

```
DF <- DF[-(Stocks_Brazil$Symbol=="A" & DF$Date=="2014-09-06")]
```

And also

```
DF <- DF[-(Symbol=="A" & Date=="2014-09-06")]
```

I  really don't know what else to do.

Thanks for reading and for any possible help

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt was close. `Stock_Brazil` should be replaced by `DF` and a `,` should be added before `]` at the end.

Give it a try.

```
DF <- DF[-(DF$Symbol== "A" & DF$Date == "2014-09-01"), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
result <- subset(DF, !(Symbol == 'A' & Date == '2014-09-06'))
```

The same expression can be used in `dplyr::filter` as well.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- DF %>% filter(!(Symbol == 'A' & Date == '2014-09-06'))
```